# How can I put only the left and right lines in red in a command?

Tags: color, memoir, line

I have successfully managed to get my subssubection between two lines. Now I want the two lines to be red, while the text remains black.

I have tried to put `\textcolor{red}` in various parts of the command, but it gives an error. How could I make the lines appear red?

This is my MVE:

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}
\renewcommand\subsubsecheadstyle{\Large\noindent\ruleline}
%\textcolor{red}
\begin{document}
    \subsubsection{Homilía (1982): Despertar}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hope this is the one, you expects:

```
\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{{\color{red}\hrulefill}\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}{\color{red}\hrulefill}}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\textcolor{red}{\hrulefill}\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\textcolor{red}{\hrulefill}}}}
\renewcommand\subsubsecheadstyle{\Large\noindent\ruleline}
\begin{document}
    \subsubsection{Homilía (1982): Despertar}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works too. Thanks.